# Two columns of images, of different width. First is fixed, second should shrink to remaining width

Tags: html, css

I can't figure out how to do this.

So far what I have is that the first column has

```
float: left
width: 400px
```

But the second column just won't fit the remaining space, no matter if they have a wrapper around them, if the wrapper has "width: 100%", if the pics have it, or any other combination I've tried. Once the width of the browser is reduced, the second column just jumps to the end of the first, it doesn't display side by side anymore. Combined with the fact that the second column's images should also be centered, and shouldn't grow larger than their natural width,  I don't know what to do anymore. None of the solutions I've found online have image examples.

The html (flask) code:

```
<div class="gallery">
    <div class="thumbnail-container">
        {% for thumb in gallery.thumbs %}
        <img class="thumb" src="{{thumb}}">
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div class="fullsize-container">
        {% for full in gallery.full %}
        <img class="full" src="{{full}}">
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

What I want in a picture (both columns should be independently scrollable):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

flexbox is good but for something this simple I would use calc in your css.  Notice the use of  which is use to comment in html.  we use this to get rid of the space between inline-block elements (if you remove it change the calc to 100% - 410px:

perhaps now inside left and right I might use flexbox for the rest.

```css
#left,#right{
border:solid black 1px;
height:250px;
display:inline-block;
}

#left{
width:400px;
}


#right{
width:calc(100% - 404px);
}

html,body{
margin:0;
padding:0;}
```

```html
<div id='left'>
    
</div><!--    
--><div id='right'>
</div>
```

Comment: How would I center the images in their own columns with this?

Comment: margin:0 auto; display:block; or using left and right as containers use flexbox

Comment: Yeah, that does it for me. Thanks.